# UK cities boundries in Ordnance survey

Tags: data, ordnance-survey

Are there any city boundaries of UK cities in the Ordnance Survey?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends how you define cities.

The [strategi](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/opendata/) dataset contains a cities layer.  If you wish to have more detail, and include large towns the [Meridian 2](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/opendata/) dataset contains an urban area layer that would be a good starting point.

You could also use the Boundary Line Data from the same source that would give you the administrative Boundary associated with particular cities.

Comment: +1 Thanks. Do you know anything about licensing issues?

Comment: It's Opendata - read the terms (PDF) http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendata/docs/os-opendata-licence.pdf

Comment: Probably better off using VectorMap District Building Outlines http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/os-vectormap-district/index.html if using at large scale.