# Looking for a Provider of UK boundary data

Tags: data, google-maps, ordnance-survey, united-kingdom

I'm working on a web project centered around the input and mapping of GIS data. We have a need to display polygons of town boundaries.

The RightMove.co.uk website has and uses this data: http://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/map.html?locationIdentifier=REGION^20140&insId=1

[image: RightMove overlaying town boundary on Google map]

**Does anyone know a provider of this information (town/city boundaries)?**

I've contacted Google sales, but they've said they don't have this data. So it appears RightMove got it from another source.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's the [Ordnance Survey OpenData](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/os-opendata.html) now. You could try the Strategi product. This has urban_region polygons, but they don't have names since they are often several towns now in a conurbation. Combining with the settlmnt_point layer you could use that to get the names.

Here's the polys and points on top of a google maps layer (done using QGIS)

[image]

As you can see, the blue polygon relates to Portishead and Redcliff Bay. Anyway, maybe you can use this.

The Ordnance Survey Strategi 
(Version: 01/2011) is available from

https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html

Also, you may be asking the same as:

[UK cities boundries in Ordnance survey](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5464/uk-cities-boundries-in-ordnance-survey)

Answer (score 2):

If you require Higher Quality City (Urban Areas) data:

**Vector Map District** is derived from a larger scale than the Stategi product mentioned
http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/os-vectormap-district/index.html

The VectorMap District Building Outlines is the most accurate and up-to-date dataset available without cost (under [OpenData Licence](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/opendata/docs/os-opendata-licence.pdf)) from the Ordnance Survey.

**Scale of the Datasets**

VectorMap District Scale
The nominal viewing scale is **1:25 000,** with a recommended viewing scale range of 1:15 000 to 1:30 000.

Strategi 
The definitive **1:250 000** scale dataset for Great Britain suited to multiple applications using a
geographical information system (GIS), computer-aided design (CAD) and digital mapping systems.

Comment: Strategi lacks most urban areas.  Vector Map is probably overkill.  The best dataset would be meridian 2.

Comment: Meridian2 is sourced from 'Strategi® 1:250 000' for Developed land use areas and place names. see page 8 on the pdf > http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/docs/user-guides/meridian-2-user-guide.pdf - Google Map in Satellite mode can be detailed enough for Vector District

Comment: Of course all this data has to be re-projected to WGS84 for the data to overlay and align onto Google Maps. QGIS can do this easily.

Answer (score 0):

www.boundaries-io.com
**I do work for boundaries io**

BS20 which is postal of Bristol..this API gets exactly what your looking for and returns simply GeoJson to integrate into GoogleMap easy.

/public/boundary/uk?postal-district=BS20

Gets you the below in googlemap, after consuming the GeoJson Response.
[image]